# Efficient way of reading a specific line from a serial communicaiton on Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port

Is it possible to read, from a serial buffer, a specific line instead of the whole buffer?

This part of the code:

```
while(USB.available()){

  int bytesSent = USB.peek(); // this is the orignal that works
  Serial.write(USB.read()); // this is the orignal that works

  if(bytesSent == 13)
  {
  countline = countline + 1;
      if(countline == 6) // desired line
      {
        Serial.println(" On Line 5");
        getnextline = 1; // tells that for the next line, I have to get the data coming
      }         
  }
      if (getnextline == 1)
      {
        int bytesStore = USB.peek();
          //Serial.println(bytesStore);
          countstoring = countstoring + 1;
      }
  delay(1);                           //This delay is necessary for successful Serial transmission                 
}
```

Gives me this:

```
18:17:12.816 -> Opening file.
18:17:12.816 -> >File opened successfully.
18:17:12.852 -> Getting File Size
18:17:12.924 -> FileSize =4483
18:17:12.924 -> Reading file:
18:17:12.959 -> 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:17:12.995 -> 2.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:17:12.995 -> 3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:17:13.067 -> 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:17:13.103 -> 5.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000   On Line 5
18:17:13.139 -> 
18:17:13.139 -> 6.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:17:13.175 -> 7.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
```

But my problem is if I try to read just, for example, the data from line 5

It will give me:

```
18:59:48.839 -> Reading file:
18:59:48.839 -> 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:59:48.874 -> 2.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:59:48.909 -> 3.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:59:48.944 -> 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
18:59:48.979 -> 5.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000      On Line 5
18:59:49.047 -> 10
18:59:49.047 -> 
18:59:49.047 -> 54
18:59:49.047 -> 646
18:59:49.047 -> .48
```

The way that I tried this was uncommenting:

```
      if (getnextline == 1)
      {
        int bytesStore = USB.peek();
        Serial.println(bytesStore);
        countstoring = countstoring + 1;
      }
```

In other words, from my read, how can I get:
"5.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000"

Comment: Are you reading a file or a (slow) serial Stream ? Your `delay(1);` is either  useless or depending on the Serial speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is already in the word "serial". You're reading data in a serial manner. That means bit by bit, byte by byte.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication

Let's say the data you're interested in is starts at byte no 200. The only thing that makes this byte byte no 200 is that there are 199 bytes in front of it.
And what is the only way to find byte no 200? you count the bytes until you reach the 200th.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling peek() you can directly read(), count the newline characters and ignore any other, until you got the correct line. then you read the next characters and work with them, until another newline happens.